# Integrate eclipse and oracle ebusiness suite

Tags: oracle, plugins, helios

How to use Oracle Ebusiness suite 11i with eclipse?
How do we integrate the suite so that I may use eclipse IDE [Helios] to perform development with regards to the .jsp and .java files present on the Server.
Server is Linux based.

Please let me know.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

11i uses Apache Jserv, so you would have to try to find an Eclipse plugin that supports that.  There doesn't seem to by anything on the plugin site.  If you're looking to upgrade to R12 (11i goes on extended support this year), then it uses oc4j which looks like it has some plugin support.    The 11i technology stack is pretty old.